# Java subclass takes 1 less argument in the constructor

Tags: java

I'm writing a simple program that displays a persons card number, name and limit in Java fx. How can i make it so that a subclass inherits one less argument in its constructor? I have 2 different card types, a debit card, that has no limit, and a credit card that I will give a limit when creating the object.

```
public AccountData(String id, String name, int limit) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.limit = limit;
}
```

So when creating a debit card subclass that extends AccountData, I do not want the limit argument, because it does not have one.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clean way would be to leave the `limit` out of your `AccountData` class (since it is obviously *not* a common property) and only introduce it in your credit card class:

```
public class AccountData {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public AccountData(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class CreditCardAccountData extends AccountData {
    private int limit;

    public CreditCardAccountData(String id, String name, int limit) {
        super(id, name);
        this.limit = limit;
    }
}
```

If you want to stick to your current approach, you can add a second constructor to your `AccountData` class and e.g. set the `limit` to a default value (maybe `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or `-1`, although the former seems more appropriate):

```
public AccountData(String id, String name) {
    this(id, name, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how to introduce it in my subclass when I leave it out of the parent class? I tried doing this but failed.

Answer (score 1):

> I have 2 different card types, a debit card, that has no limit, and a credit card that I will give a limit when creating the object.

Then presumably `CreditCard` and `DebitCard` are subclasses of the `AccountData` type; so make the `limit` a property of the `CreditCard` subclass, not `AccountData`:

```
class AccountData {
  AccountData(String id, String name) { ... }
}

class CreditCard extends AccountData {
  CreditCard(String id, String name, int limit) {
    super(id, name);
    this.limit = limit;
  }
}

class DebitCard extends AccountData {
  DebitCard(String id, String name) {
    super(id, name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another constructor for debit cards in the super class that takes less arguments

Comment: No problem! I’m new to this stack overflow thing so if that fixed your problem and you could mark it as the answer that would be awesome!

Comment: it did, i gotta wait like 10 minutes before i can mark this as the answer tho, ill make sure to remember.

Comment: This doesn't really help: either you are leaving the value of `limit` uninitialised by the new constructor (which is dangerous, because the default value might not have the desired semantics), or you're setting it to an explicit default (in which case, why not just invoke the existing constructor with the explicit default?).

Answer (score 0):

Just write a new constructor with less argument something like this:

```
class DebitCard extends AccountData {

 public DebitCard(String id, String name) {
    super(id, name, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
 }

}
```

Comment: but it will make limit to 0 in parent class

Comment: since it is a debit card, we should set limit to max value. Point is you can pass whatever default value you want for the subclass.

Comment: same answered by @marvin

Comment: yeah he answered few seconds before me... so i did not see that. Anyways you get the idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, I will suggest to rework on design as it won't be a good idea to have one child class with different sets of inherited members and other child class having different, both inheriting the same parent class.But, for adhoc, I can suggest to make **private int limit**, in **AccountData** and **CreditCard** class. In this, way you can protect your member.
If you just have a constructor with less argument, will create issues. As, if limit is public, it can be accessed from DebitCard class as it will inherit.
So, better to make private int limit to both AccountData and CreditCard class.